# Set initial value of lookup field with SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns attached (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spservices

I use SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns to link two lookup fields in a custom NewForm for a custom list.

What I want to do is give an option to create a new item, based on a currently created item, and I have all the values for the previous item available, but I have a hard time setting the values of the lookup fields which are using SPCascadeDropdowns to a given value.

I found that I could use the following to change the value of the fields:

```
$("select[title='ParentLookupField']").val(prevParentLookupFieldValue);
$("select[title='ChildLookupField']").val(prevChildLookupFieldValue);
```

This seems to work on the parent column of the SPCascadeDropdowns, but even though it changes
the value, it doesnt seem like it triggers the change for SPCascadeDropdowns, because the child column does not get updated according to the change in parent.

Example:

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "ChildList",

        relationshipListParentColumn: "ParentValue",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",

        parentColumn: "ParentLookupField",
        childColumn: "ChildLookupField",

        simpleChild: true,

        completefunc: function () {
                $("select").each(function (index, item) {
                    var title = item.title;
                    if (title === ""ParentLookupField"," || title === ""ChildLookupField",") {
                        $(item).find("option").each(function (index, item) {
                            var text = $(item).text();
                            if (text === "(None)") {
                                $(item).remove();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

$("select[title='ParentLookupField']").val(prevParentLookupFieldValue);
$("select[title='ChildLookupField']").val(prevChildLookupFieldValue);
```

So, how can I with SPCascadeDropdowns set the initial value of the lookup fields and make SPCascadeDropdowns trigger changes for the child field?

Answer (score 0):

That depends how the on change is registered to the drop down.

If you set it's value using the `$control.val(new value)`, you may want to call the change event manually.

I use this to fire onchange events safely on any browser:

```
//I have a utility class called KWizComCascadingLookup defined earlier
KWizComCascadingLookup.FireEvent = function (elm, event) {
    if ("createEvent" in document) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event, false, true);
        elm.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    else
        elm.fireEvent("on" + event);
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
KWizComCascadingLookup.FireEvent(elm, "change");
```

Your event should be called now. It is strange that the jQuery .val() doesn't invoke it though.